# When Shrinking size of window I need to use media query to have text fill across the page to be more readable if that is possible

Tags: html, css, media-queries, width

As shown by the arrows the text and image need to expand as I'm shrinking for better readability.

[image: As shown by the arrows the text and image need to expand as I'm shrinking for better readability.]

I tried using

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
    #container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.centerpage {
   margin: auto;
   width: 50%;
}

.content {
   color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
   width: 100%;
}

.img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
   border: 5px solid white;
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="container" class="centerpage">
    <div class="content">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</section>
```

Is there anything I can add that might help? I tried posting without including a lot of the content to keep it simple.

Comment: Maybe.. it You share your code.. or even better, replicate the problem in a living example we may be able to help you. But wizards, we are not.

Comment: Sorry very new to this, I've updated it thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Try this `.centerpage { margin: auto; width: 100%; }` to have a width of 100% instead of 50%.